# Setting system fonts for specific languages

Tags: windows-vista, fonts, control-panel

Vista allows you to set the default UI font for most European languages by going into the Control Panel > Personalization > Window Appearance > Classic Appearance Properties > Advanced. (The default font is *Segoe UI*.)

But how do you do this for complex scripts? For example, the default system font for Hebrew is *Gisha*, but I'd like to change it to something more legible, like *Arial Hebrew*. Where can I find the settings for this?

Answer (score 1):

From [Change the default Windows XP fonts](http://it.megocollector.com/?p=77):

> Use regedit and change the following
>   two keys of "MS Shell Dlg 2" and "MS Dlg"
>   to whatever font you want. Make
>   certain that `C:\windows\fonts`
>   already contains that font.

Here is a .reg file that can change the default fonts:

> `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]`
>   `"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"`
>  
>   `"MS Shell Dlg"="Microsoft Sans Serif"`

For more info : [Source1](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776266.aspx), [Source2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282187), [Source3](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/lofiversion/index.php?t7663.html).

Comment: I think this changes the default font only for the default script (Latin). How would I change the default font for another script (e.g. Hebrew)?

Comment: "MS Shell Dlg*" is the default system font, but any other font can be substituted. For an example see [Change the Default System Fonts in Windows 7](http://www.davidjnice.com/articles/windows7_fonts.html). Just be warned that font-names must be exactly specified and are case-sensitive.