# Windows 10 displaying the wrong font

Tags: windows-10, fonts, regional-settings

Windows 10 has started displaying the wrong fonts in certain areas, most frequently tab labels and some other dialog boxes. It should be displaying Segoe UI instead of what I think is MS Sans Serif.

**To reiterate, 99% of the fonts are the correct font face and size; only a handful of cases seem to revert to stupidly large MS Sans Serif.**

I managed to solve this problem once before by tweaking some regional or language setting back to US (from Australia). Unfortunately, I can't seem to replicate the fix by doing what I did before, and I cannot find any useful information, as just about every search is just full of more general font-scaling or blurry-font issues.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/84045/windows-default-font-messed-up-but-not-everywhere) closely describes my problem, but for Windows XP, and the suggested resolution does not work in my case.

## Examples

- Stupidly big tab labels
  [image: npp]
  [image: ssms2]
- Stupidly big dialog text
  [image: ssms1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CCleaner Software font cache cleaning and restart your pc see if the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: I believe it is going to be fixed , lets see what  happens

Comment: hi did you solve the problem ?

Comment: The issue fixed itself before I had a chance to do anything. As such I believe it was most likely some sort of caching issue as you suggested, so I've marked your answer as accepted.